Where is file path information stored?
Where is the file path infromation stored on ext4 file systems, within partitions?
Obviously, it's stored on the drive itself because the structure is on the device itself (i.e. folders stay folders when transferring a disk drive between devices).

The filesystem finds a pointer to the / directory in the partition's metainfo. / contains inodes (pointers to) of the top level directories (/*), which contain inodes of their subdirectories, and so forth. The "path" to an object is generated, and is not stored anywhere.

The question and answer are not specific to ext4, they work for all inode based filesystems.

Path information is not stored at all.  There is no entry in ext4 called /usr/bin/ls.
What we have are inodes and directories.
So there's a directory called /.  This has an inode (typically number 2).  Inodes contain various information about the file (permissions, ownership, etc).
Inside this directory will be an entry called usr, and that has an inode number associated with it.  One of these pieces of information in this inode is that this is a directory.
So we open this directory and find inside it an entry called bin.  Which has yet another inode...
And inside this directory we find an entry called ls which is a file with execution permissions and so on.
So there's no entry called /usr/bin/ls; instead there are 4 entries ; / and inside / we find usr and inside usr we find bin and inside bin we find ls.
Each of those 4 entries has an inode and associated metadata.
The path is merely a construct that follows the chain of directories to reach the file.

For OP: you can visualize this concept as a tree, where every / becomes a line which connects the preceding element to the next (in this case: a line would connect / to usr, a line would connect usr to bin and a line would connect bin to ls); when done for each possible location on the filesystem, this creates a tree-like structure; the path to an element can be inferred, starting from this tree-like structure, literally by the "path" one has to follow in order to get from / to the target node. https://www2.lawrence.edu/fast/GREGGJ/CMSC480/file_system/file_system2.png

The "tree" visualisation is excellent, but incomplete. The possibility of additional links (both "hard" and "symbolic") means that some parts of the tree can have alternative routes which resolve to the same actual file. My visualisation of this is that tree branches may also be interconnected by ivy.

So it forms a tree structure, do directories get their own separate entries then?

@Paul_Pedant, though there are no hard links to directories (in sensible recent systems), and symlinks are more like labels saying "maybe look there", instead of real connections, so as far as the directory tree (excluding files) is concerned, it is a tree.
